# Access denied issue when I try to access a shared drive from Django running in Apache

Tags: django, apache

This is the error message I am getting in Django. I am running in an Apache server hosted on Windows NT.

```
[Error 5] Access is denied: u'Shared drive path'.
```

I think this is because the Apache service is running as a different user

Answer (score 0):

You answered it on your own. The service in running as a different user, so the drive isn't mounted as e.g. "G:\"

You have to pass full UNC-paths and grant access to the www-user. That worked for me.